# can't print the value of json object in django

Tags: python, django

I have this json object in ajax_data variable

```
{
    "columns[0][data]": "0", 
    "columns[1][name]": "", 
    "columns[5][searchable]": "true", 
    "columns[5][name]": "", 
    "columns[4][search][regex]": "false", 
    "order[0][dir]": "asc", 
    "length": "10", 
}
```

I have converted it using json.loads() function like.

```
ajax_data = json.loads(ajax_data)
```

I want to get the value if "order[0][dir]" and "columns[0][data]" but if i print it using

```
ajax_data['order'][0]['dir]
```

its giving error :

```
KeyError at /admin/help
'order'
```

But same code works if i access it for length key then it works.

Comment: Your key is a string "[order][0][dir]" -- it's not actually an array at that point. I think this should work: ajax_data["[order][0][dir]"]. But you probably want to figure another way to store/access the data if you want to work with an actual array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys you have used are actually not a good way of implementation.

```
{
    "columns[0][data]": "0", 
    "columns[1][name]": "", 
    "columns[5][searchable]": "true", 
    "columns[5][name]": "", 
    "columns[4][search][regex]": "false", 
    "order[0][dir]": "asc", 
    "length": "10", 
}
```

Instead of this you should hav gone for

```
{
    "columns": [
        {"data": "0", "name": "", "searchable": "true", "name": "", "search": {
            "regex": "false"}
        },
        {"data": "0", "name": "", "searchable": "true", "name": ""," search": {
            "regex": "false"}},
        {"data": "0", "name": "", "searchable": "true", "name": "", "search": {
            "regex": "false"}},
        {"data": "0", "name": "", "searchable": "true", "name": "", "search": {
            "regex": "false"}},
        {"data": "0", "name": "", "searchable": "true", "name": "", "search": {
            "regex": "false"}},
        {"data": "0", "name": "", "searchable": "true", "name": "", "search": {
            "regex": "false"}},
    ],
    "order": [
        {"dir": "asc"}
    ],
    "length": "10"
}
```

In this case ajax_data['order'][0]['dir] will result in value "asc"

For your current implementation the key is "order[0][dir]"

That is go for

`ajax_data["order[0][dir]"]`

Hope you understood the issue.

Structuring of json is very important when dealing with APIs. Try to restructure your json which will help for future too.

Comment: ajax_data["order[0][dir]"] this is working, but i did not create this structure. I am using metronic ajax datatables, and there is a file datatables.js which returns values of tables in this format. metronic datatables plugins is compatible with PHP code, but i have to use it in django, that's why i am facing some issues in it.

Comment: Okay. Then it is fine. Happy that you got your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `length` is a key in that json object, and `order` is not.  The key names are the *entire* strings inside the quotes: `columns[0][data]`, `order[0][dir]`, etc.

Those are unusual key names, but perfectly valid.